# Clicking on a button which take you to the main menu of android existing applications

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi i'm writing a "Quit" (exit button) i want it take me to the main menu of android existing applications i'm using javascript ,css and HTML it's a mobile application written with HTML5 
Any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to achieve this. Android does not permit it.